# Error with onChange Trigger, cannot call UI

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. at CheckInventory(onChange2:13:27)

I am getting the above error when my code runs. I have it set to an onchange trigger. It checks the values in one column of my spreadsheet and compares it to another. I don't believe the issue lies in that, but rather somewhere else? my code is as follows;

```
// Check inventory and send email on Change to Column AA (27)
function CheckInventory() {
  // Fetch the current inventory)
  
  var currentRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getActiveRange().getRow();
  var currentColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getActiveRange().getColumn();
  var currentInventoryRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getRange(currentRow,11); 
  var currentInventory = currentInventoryRange.getValue();
  var oneMonthInventoryRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getRange(currentRow,27); 
  var oneMonthInventory = oneMonthInventoryRange.getValue();
  var currentSKU = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getRange(currentRow,1).getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  
  // Check totals sales
  if (currentColumn === 27){
  if (currentInventory < oneMonthInventory){

  // Fetch the email address
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("B2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  
  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = 'Item SKU ' + currentSKU + ' inventory is low! Reorder now.'; // Second column
  var subject = 'Low Inventory Notification: ' + currentSKU;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }}
}
```

Any thoughts on why this is breaking and not triggering properly?

I have tried updating the ui line and checked it to ensure it was written properly, but it did not fix it.

Comment: Do you have multiple onChange triggers?  The error says `onChange2`.  And why are you using onChange.  That occurs if you add a line or tab or delete a line.  In other words alter the  sheet structure.

Comment: I used to have 2 onChange scripts, one for testing and a 2nd that became this. I got rid of the first one. But its just the name of the script not the function.

Comment: I can tell you I can not duplicate your error.  I created a simple installed onChange trigger with a UI alert and it works.  If I delete a row the alert is displayed.

Comment: Weird! Okay Ill go back to it delete all scripts and re-write it to and see what happens!

Comment: The only way i know of where this error message would occur is if it were used as a custom function.  If you had put `=CheckInventory()` in a cell.

Comment: Could you provide more details about the `ui` variable? it seems that you are calling the `getUi` method however I don't see in your code the implementation of the alert, you may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs) related to displaying alerts using this method.